Is there a Fairy Chess piece that takes up less than one square on the board?
I have never seen a piece that doesn't take up a full square. Is there any chess variant where there is a piece that can share a square with another piece?

If you want a specific fairy piece designed to share space with other pieces, I don't know of any established/well-known ones. Perhaps unsurprisingly, people have made up some obscure fairy pieces that do this, but not necessarily in serious variants. Examples: https://www.chess.com/forum/view/community/invent-the-new-worst-chess-piece-ever?page=12#comment-28502840 https://www.chess.com/forum/view/community/invent-the-new-worst-chess-piece-ever?page=13#comment-30574334
Edit: I'm not sure if this counts, but some fairy pieces could work like vehicles or carriers of other pieces, such as Carrier from https://www.chessvariants.com/piececlopedia.dir/noveltypieces.html
There are quite a few variants that broadly allow multiple pieces occupying the same square, but don't have designated fairy pieces that specifically do this unlike other pieces. See eg. Variant in which two pieces can occupy a single square
Some variants have similar properties but are not quite the same thing:
Variants where pieces can be stacking. Eg. https://www.chess.com/forum/view/general/stack-chess https://www.chessvariants.com/difftaking.dir/pillar.html
Variants where a square can be occupied by a superposition of multiple pieces/piece types, like inspired by quantum physics. Eg. https://quantumai.google/cirq/experiments/unitary/quantum_chess https://www.reddit.com/r/chess/comments/12f81jo/quantum_chess_variant/ (There are several variants called quantum chess or similar. On the other hand, there are variants where a piece can be on multiple squares like https://www.chessvariants.com/d.betza/chessvar/tirebiter.html  I can't find variants right now that allows both pieces on multiple squares and pieces sharing squares, but wouldn't be surprised if they exist)
variants where boards have a third dimension and pieces on the same location horizontally but not vertically can interact, eg. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragonchess
Pieces that can be passed through by riders but cannot really share squares in a position(https://www.chessvariants.com/rules/re-ghostchess)
Fractal boards where a square on one board corresponds to multiple squares on another board in some way(eg. https://www.chessvariants.com/rules/fractal-chess https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=24065144)
Pieces can merge and/or split, often based on their abilities, so even if technically it's not called sharing a square it's equivalent in some ways. There are many variants, eg. https://www.chessvariants.com/difftaking.dir/merger.html https://www.chessvariants.com/rules/fluid-chess https://www.chessvariants.com/other.dir/fusion.html https://www.chessvariants.com/tag/Rules%3AFission https://www.chessvariants.com/tag/Rules%3AFusion
Some sources: https://www.chessvariants.com/boardrules.dir/multocc.html https://www.chessvariants.com/boardrules.dir/crowded1.html

Answers to this question are also relevant
